# Best approach for deleting when using Array.combination()?

Tags: ruby, loops

I want to compare every object in lectures with each other and if some_condition is true, the second object has to be deleted:

```
toDelete=[]
lectures.combination(2).each do |first, second|
  if (some_condition)
   toDelete << second
  end
end
toDelete.uniq!
lectures=lectures-toDelete
```

I got some weird errors while trying to delete inside the .each loop, so I came up with this approach.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

EDIT after first comments:

I wanted to keep the source code free of unnecessary things, but now that you ask:
The elements of the lectures array are hashes containing data of different university lectures, like the name, room,the calendar weeks in which they are taught and begin and end time.

I parse the timetables of all student groups to get this data, but because some lectures are held in more than one student group and these sometimes differ in the weeks they are taught, I compare them with each other. If the compared ones only differ in certain values, I add the values from the second object to the first object and delete the second object. That's why.

The errors when deleting while in .each-loop: When using the Rails Hash.diff method, I got something like "Cannot  convert Symbol to Integer". Turns out there was suddenly an Integer value of 16 in the array, although I tested before the loop that there are only hashes in the array...

Debugging is really hard if you have 9000 hashes.

EDIT:
Sample Data:

```
lectures = [ {:day=>0, :weeks=>[11, 12, 13, 14], :begin=>"07:30", :end=>"09:30", :rooms=>["Li201", "G221"], :name=>"TestSubject1", :kind=>"Vw", :lecturers=>["WALDM"], :tut_groups=>["11INM"]}, 
{:day=>0, :weeks=>[11, 12, 13, 14], :begin=>"07:30", :end=>"09:30", :rooms=>["Li201", "G221"], :name=>"TestSubject1", :kind=>"Vw", :lecturers=>["WALDM"], :tut_groups=>["11INM"]} ]
```

Comment: any example inputs and outputs please..

Comment: What does `lectures` look like?

Comment: Example of the "weird errors" would help.

Comment: what is *some_condition*?

Comment: We need sample data. Asking us to imagine it won't work. See http://sscce.org/.

Comment: I added sample data of the lectures array. Though I really don't see the reason for needing sample data here. The basic question was just how to handle it if you need to delete something within a array.combination(2).each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
cleaned_lectures = lectures.combination(2).reject{|first, second| some_condition}
```